# Yahoo authenticate & fetch profile details iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, yahoo-api

I've listed here **Yahoo Integration steps** which I've followed.

- Step 1. I went to http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/
- Step 2. Downloaded entire framework from here - http://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc
- Step 3. I did Drag & drop that framework into my project.
- Step 4. Enabled flag `fno-objc-arc` for yahoo framework files.
- Step 5. I did `#import "YOSSocial.h"` in my viewController's header file.
- Step 6. In view did load, I placed **Code block 1** to create a session object.
- Step 7. On a button click, I invoke, **Code block 2**.
- Step 8. In AppDelegate.m, I've implemented method as **Code block 3**.
- Step 9. I receive `oauth_token` & `oauth_verifier` in redirection.

**Code block 1**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.session = [YOSSession sessionWithConsumerKey:@"ConsumerKeyHere"
                                           andConsumerSecret:@"ConsumerSecretKeyHere"
                                            andApplicationId:@"AppKey"];
    BOOL hasSession = [self.session resumeSession];
    if(hasSession == FALSE) {
        // custom call back URL which will redirect to our-app.
        // 10.0.0.76/iOS/callback.php redirects 
        // to com.mymobileapps.currentApp.yahoo
        [self.session 
           sendUserToAuthorizationWithCallbackUrl:
           @"http://10.0.0.76/iOS/callback.php"];
    } else {
        [self sendRequests];
    }
}
```

**Code block 2**

```
- (void)sendRequests {
    // initialize a user request for the logged-in user
    YOSUserRequest *request = [YOSUserRequest requestWithSession:self.session];

    // fetch the user's profile data
    [request fetchProfileWithDelegate:self];
}

- (void)requestDidFinishLoading:(YOSResponseData *)data {
    // parse the response text string into a dictionary
    NSDictionary *rspData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data.responseText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSDictionary *profileData = [rspData objectForKey:@"profile"];

    // format a string using the nickname object from the profile.
    NSString *welcomeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey %@ %@!",
                             [profileData objectForKey:@"givenName"],
                             [profileData objectForKey:@"familyName"]];
    NSLog(@"welcometext is %@",welcomeText);
    self.lblProfile.text = welcomeText;
}
```

**Code block 3**

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    NSString *str = [[url description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"com.mymobileapps.currentApp.yahoo://oauth-response?oauth_token=" withString:@""];
    NSArray *ar = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"&oauth_verifier="];
    NSLog(@"oauth_token is %@",[ar objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"oauth_verifier is %@",[ar objectAtIndex:1]);
    // How my session will get updated now with valid authentication done?
    return YES;
}
```

I followed each & every step as described here - http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec/ & I also implemented redirection as described here - [How to redirect from Yahoo to my IOS app after authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090688/how-to-redirect-from-yahoo-to-my-ios-app-after-authentication)

**QUESTION** is as follows.
I am still not able to fetch user-profile details like gender, date of birth etc. That is - From **Code block 2**, I receive data as nil.

***What is missing in my code to retrieve data of user-profile?***

Other reference.

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

Above code illustrates How Google+ framework handles redirection & manages with local session. In case of Yahoo, I don't find any details which is helpful to update local-session of mobile app.

***Edit:***
If it is not possible through Yahoo OAuth, **How is it possible to fetch basic profile details (like - gender, date of birth, email ID, name etc.) from Yahoo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

NOTE: You would be needing an intermediate server for that.

- **Step 01.** Download PHP yahoo framework http://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php
- **Step 02.** Start WAMP/XAMPP server.
- **Step 03.** Obtain URL

  - example - `http://10.0.0.76/iOS/yos-social-php-master/sample/sampleapp.php`
- **Step 04.** Get back to XCode project.
- **Step 05.** Open XIB, Put a button for Yahoo & connect IBAction method.
- **Step 06.** In IBAction method, navigate to obtained URL from iOS App to URL. See **Code Block 1**
- **Step 07.** Add method in AppDelegate.m for handling redirection from Server to your mobile App. See **Code Block 2**
- **Step 08.** Make sure your app is capable handling Redirection. Open your project-info.plist as source-code & make sure you have valid `URL types`, `URL identifier` & `URL Schemes`. as indicated in **Code Block 3**
- **Step 09.** Now your mobile app is ready for redirection from server.
- **Step 10.** Open `yourLocalServer/iOS/yos-social-php-master/sample/sampleapp.php` file. (https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php/blob/master/sample/sampleapp.php)
- **Step 11.** Comment code from 97 to 106.
- **Step 12.** Put code as indicated in **Code Block 4**
- **Step 13.** Run your project, Click on button from iOS App.
- **Step 14.** App will navigate to your site-page. Site page will do the authentication & get the profile details.
- **Step 15.** As soon as authentication is done, site-page will redirect back to your-mobile-app with details like - Gender, Full name, date of birth, guid, profile picture url etc.

***Summary***

Mobile App navigates to Server -> Server manages authentication via OAuth-php. Once authenticated Server retrieves profile details & server indicates safari to navigate back to - your-mobile-App. Your-mobile-app gets all details in Code Block

**Code Block 1**

```
- (IBAction)connectYahoo:(id)sender {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
           openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
           @"http://yourLocalServer/iOS/yos-social-php-master/sample/sampleapp.php"
      ]];
}
```

**Code Block 2**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

    if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"com.yourcompany.app.fsq"]) {
        return [self.obj_LoginHomeVCtr.foursquare handleOpenURL:url];
    } else if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"com.yourcompany.app.googleplus"]){
        return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];

    }else if([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"fb188315544652080"]){
        return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];
    } else if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"com.yourcompany.app.yahoo"]){
        STLog(@"URL is %@",url);
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Code block 3**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.app.yahoo</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.yourcompany.app.yahoo</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**Code block 4**

```
  else if($hasSession && $profile) {
      $string = "com.yourcompany.app.yahoo://response?birthdate=" . $profile->birthdate . "&familyName=" . $profile->familyName. " " . $profile->givenName . "&gender=" . $profile->gender . "&guid=" . $profile->guid . "&image=" . $profile->image->imageUrl;
      echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;URL='. $string .'">';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetchProfileWithDelegate:` ([source here](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc/blob/master/Source/YOSSocial/YOSUserRequest.m)) builds a URL and sets some header info, then passes this data to `[YOSRequestClient -sendAsyncRequestWithDelegate:]` ([source here](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc/blob/master/Source/YOSSocial/YOSRequestClient.m)).

The request client then creates a `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` and starts a connection.

Once the data is downloaded (if any) `YOSResponseData` takes over and creates a new object from the downloaded data ([source code here](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc/blob/master/Source/YOSSocial/YOSResponseData.m)).

There is no code path I can see that would allow the `serviceResponseData` object passed in to be `nil`.  You should at least be able to see `[data didSucceed]`, which will tell you if the HTTP response was `< 400`.  Oddly enough, if the server just opens and closes the connection with no HTTP response, I believe `[data didSucceed] == YES` even though it obviously didn't succeed (since 0 < 400).

It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong.  My guess is that since [the last commit was 4 years ago](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc/commit/fbddb1cab3568d3a85e6274714a5252d06d690c7), and the company has gone through significant restructuring since then, the project has been abandoned and nobody has bothered making a note of it.

Update: In addition to having no updates for 4 years, Yahoo's [developer forum for this software has been closed](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Y-OS-SDKs/).  I don't think Yahoo's API for this software is working any more. –

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I already have added `fetchProfileWithDelegate:` in **Code Block 2** As session within application doesn't have authentication, App will receive nothing from yahoo.

Comment: Source-code links are meaningless. I already have added link of entire Yahoo framework in my question itself.

Comment: O_o the last commit was `4 years ago` o_O ! That makes me feel nervous.

Comment: Also, their developer forum for asking questions has been closed. I think I did read and understand your question. I don't think Yahoo's API for this software is working any more.

Comment: For Android & other web-platform, everything seems to be working fine. Is there other way around to fetch profile details from Yahoo for iOS?

Comment: You could use a tool like Charles Proxy to sniff traffic from the Android client, compare it to the iOS client, and modify the iOS client to send the same requests as the Android client.

Comment: No. That is not going to work because it navigates to native browser & navigates back to app.

Comment: It's open source, look at the code and find the bug. In four years anything could be broken.

Answer (score 0):

From the Yahoo docs you linked here are a few things to check:

- Check that you are requesting and receiving approval for the correct permissions from the user
- Inspect the `YOSResponseData` object, if an error occurred it should contain an `NSError` object.
- It also contains an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object.  Check the response header and status code.

You've probably checked this stuff already, if so add the results to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the updated Yahoo iOS SDK without going through so many steps:  https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc