# Login with Yahoo in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, yahoo, yahoo-api, openurl

I implemented the **Login with Yahoo** functionality in my native app.

I got the code from: [Github](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc).
 It works fine to login in safari

but `I can't able to redirect to the app after Login.`

It shows like:

[image]

**If I pressed close button, nothing is going to happen.**
**Help me to solve this.**

Thank you.,

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the following SO Q&A's , the solution is given here step by step :-

[Yahoo authenticate & fetch profile details iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901375/yahoo-authenticate-fetch-profile-details-ios/21024121#21024121)

[How to redirect from Yahoo to my IOS app after authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090688/how-to-redirect-from-yahoo-to-my-ios-app-after-authentication)

Check the first answer of this forum by yahoo too :- [Oath Yahoo Redirect Issue](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OAuth-General-Discussion-YDN-SDKs/How-to-redirect-from-Yahoo-to/1380536664651-5883b0a6-304c-48b6-ad6b-9536615f28c1)